# Why can't I receive my address through the People API

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-people-api

I'm trying to get my set addresses in my Google Account through the People API.

I request the

> `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.addresses.read`

scope for the Oauth2 consent window through Javascript.

I have enabled the addresses scope in my console api and

```
$service->people->get('people/me', [
        'personFields' => 'addresses,names,emailAddresses,genders'
    ]);
```

This is effectively how i gain the people object.
For some reason addresses isn't populated, what could be the issue?

Comment: Go to https://myaccount.google.com/profile and makes you have a profile set.   Also make sure you have also requested the profile scope.   It would help if you include all of your code actually

Comment: @DaImTo thank you the profile fixed it. I assumed having my addresses in google maps would be enough, appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the user has their address set in their profile https://myaccount.google.com/profile

also you may need to add the profile scope as well.